# Show $|\left(e^{-ixt}-1 \right)/t| \le |x|$, $x ,t\ne 0$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Show 
$$\left|\frac{e^{-ixt}-1}{t}\right| \le |x|$$ 
for all real $x \ne 0$ and all real $t \ne 0$.

I tried taylor theorem but as the reminder is complex, I don't see how to get the result.

Comment: First step: denote $\alpha=xt$. You need to prove that $\left|e^{-i\alpha}-1\right|\leq|\alpha|$ for $\alpha\neq0$

Comment: See also: [Prove $|e^{i\theta} -1| \leq |\theta|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584498/prove-ei-theta-1-leq-theta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by @Dennis Gulko in a comment, the task is to prove that $|\mathrm e^{-\mathrm is}-1|\leqslant|s|$ for every real number $s$. But the function $u:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, $t\mapsto\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it}$, has derivative $u'(t)=-\mathrm i\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it}$, whose modulus is (at most) $1$ everywhere, hence 
$$
|u(s)-u(0)|\leqslant|s-0|\cdot\sup\{|u'(t)|\mid0\leqslant t\leqslant s\}=|s|.
$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align}
\exp(-ixt) - 1 &= \cos(xt) - i \sin(xt) - 1\\
& = -\left(2 \sin^2(xt/2) + 2i \cos(xt/2) \sin(xt/2)\right)\\
&= -2i \sin(xt/2) \left(\cos(xt/2) - i \sin(xt/2)\right)\\
& = -2i \sin(xt/2) \exp(-ixt/2)
\end{align}
Hence, $$\vert \exp(-ixt) - 1 \vert = \vert -2i \sin(xt/2) \exp(-ixt/2) \vert = 2 \vert \sin(xt/2) \vert$$