# Proof of $|e^{i\theta} -1| \leq |\theta|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, complex-numbers, exponential-function

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/584507/978073
In the above answer given by Julien, They made use of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

They rewrote the LHS of the inequality as $$\int_0^\theta ie^{it}\mathrm{d}t$$
and left us, the reader, to finish the thought.
I understand the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus but I somehow fail to see how that proves the inequality.
With the way I understand FTC, it's that the integral is lesser than (or equal to) [ Maximum Value of Function ]*[ Difference of Limits ]

Which would be $$e^{i\theta}*[\theta-0]$$

But it doesn't help the inequality, does it?

It seems like its easy to grasp but somehow its going right over my head. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $|ie^{it}| =1$. So $|\int_0^\theta ie^{it}\mathrm{d}t| \le |\int_0^\theta dt|=|\theta|$

Comment: Thank You!! Much appreciated.

Comment: As general advice, the triangle inequality is among the first tools to consider when inequalities and integrals arise together.

Answer (score 2):

There is a direct geometric way. The distance from the point $A=(\cos \theta,\sin\theta)$ to the point $B=(1,0)$ is less than the arc length between $A$ and $B,$ which is equal $\theta.$ The inequality is strict if $A\neq B.$

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I was looking to see where my understanding of FTC lacked, hence the specific question. Thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Once you apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, take the absolute value of both sides and then use the triangle inequality:
$$
\left| e^{i\theta} -1 \right| = 
\left| \int_0^\theta i e^{it} dt \right| \leq 
\int_0^\theta \left| i e^{it} \right| dt = 
\int_0^\theta 1 dt = \theta.$$